# Text to speech portion of code (VB.NET) works fine on windows 7 but not on windows 10

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SAPI As Object
    Select Case TextBox1.Text
        Case "1"
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.picture1
                RichTextBox1.Text = "Information here."
                SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
                SAPI.speak(RichTextBox1.Text)
    End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

On two windows 7 machines the pictures and text appear first and then the TTS happens. While on two win10 machines the speech happens first and then the picture and text appear.

I've tried adding a try catch and finally statement and setting up a delay but the problem still persists!

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Update for blackwood

```
    Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SAPI As Object
    Select Case TextBox1.Text
        Case "1"
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.picture1
                RichTextBox1.Text = "Information here."
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
                SAPI.speak(RichTextBox1.Text)
    End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to show the code **with** the attempt to delay the sound.

Comment: Windows 10 completely overhauled the speech api. Because Cortana.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't think it has anything to do with any overhaul; it's just that the screen is not updated (yet) before the TTS executes. I'd suggest to do the playback on a separate (background) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try sticking an [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) in there just before the `SAPI = CreateObject` call. Though it's not *the* solution, it's the easiest to implement. It'll cause the window get updated (the [message loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) is handled) before continuing.

*If* that works, go for the real solution: a [background thread](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315577) or [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674902.aspx) (whenever possible) for the playback of the TTS.

Comment: Thank you @RobIII! Adding the Application.DoEvent has fixed the issue for the win10 user so I will look into the async/await you mentioned.